# Vacuum Pump Power Calculation

Tags: pressure, pumps, vacuum

This may be a silly question, but I'm not a mechanical engineering. What's the best way to calculate the energy required to reduce the pressure of a gas stream below atmospheric pressure? Obviously you could work out the energy for isentropic expansion and apply an efficiency factor, but this seems like it may be inaccurate. I know my stream's mass flow rate, temperature and desired final pressure.

Answer (score 4):

Different techniques have been developed to evaluate the
efficiency of energy use by a vacuum pump. Most vacuum pump manufacturers catalog
their test results, including brake horsepower (actual hp) and cfm vs. vacuum level. Fairly
accurate evaluations of power needs can be made from such information sources.
 For example, the relative efficiency of different pumps can be obtained by calculating the
cfm of free air removed per horsepower. Or input horsepower can be compared to the "fluid
power horsepower" delivered, which is proportional to the product of gauge vacuum and air
flow rate. All comparisons must be made at the same specific vacuum level, usually at 20
in. Hg or above.

e.g. check this source http://www.tuthillvacuumblower.com/dam/357.pdf